# Div's can not be placed over each other

Tags: html, twitter

I think it is a little issue I overlooked, but I can use some help.

In the code below (wich a part of it is mine) I try to place the "twitter" div above the "wrapper" div. I tried different things like the z-index, but without any success. Can someone help me place this two div's over each other? - Thanks

code:

```
<head>
<title>Proto Format, grafisch ontwerp &amp; concept.</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="Proto2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style type="text/css">
#twitter {
height:auto;
width:auto;
z-index:100;
margin-left:500px;
margin-top:100px;
}

#wrapper{

margin-left: auto;
margin-right:auto;
z-index:auto;
}

#content{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
height:800px;
}


</style>

</head>


<body bgcolor="#BA830E" link="#006C8C" vlink="#006C8C" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

<div id="content">

<div id="twitter">
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 1,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#666666'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#',
      color: '#666666',
      links: '#006C8C'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('chantalheeg').start();
</script>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
<!-- ImageReady Slices (visie.psd) -->
<table width="989" height="1012" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Tabel_01">

    <tr>
        <td height="132" colspan="5" background="afbeeldingen/klein-2kolom_01.gif">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="198" height="811" rowspan="5" background="afbeeldingen/klein-2kolom_02.gif">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <img src="afbeeldingen/spacer.gif" width="1" height="132" alt=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width="235" height="366" rowspan="3"><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="235" height="366">
          <param name="movie" value="afbeeldingen/menu-links/menulinks-visie.swf">
          <param name="quality" value="high">
          <embed src="afbeeldingen/menu-links/menulinks-visie.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="235" height="366"></embed>
        </object></td>
        <td height="117" colspan="4" background="afbeeldingen/klein-2kolom_04.gif">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <img src="afbeeldingen/spacer.gif" width="1" height="117" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="69" colspan="4" background="afbeeldingen/klein-2kolom_05.gif">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <img src="afbeeldingen/spacer.gif" width="1" height="69" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td width="12" height="493" rowspan="2" background="afbeeldingen/klein-2kolom_06.gif">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="260" height="493" rowspan="2" align="left" valign="top" background="afbeeldingen/essentie6.gif">

        <span class="titeltekst"><br><br>Visie  Proto Format</span><span class="tekst"><br>
            <br>
        </span>
          <span class="tekst">Proto Format maakt in opdracht reclame en promotiemiddelen voor verschillende
          bedrijven en instanties. We zijn altijd op zoek naar de juiste manier om een bedrijf of product te promoten en ontwikkelen een werkwijze om hieraan vorm te geven. We houden niet van standaardwerk en spannen ons er dan ook altijd voor in
          om, veelal samen met de klant, tot iets te komen dat net even dat stukje extra geeft.
          <br>
          <br>
      </span>


      </td>
        <td width="13" height="493" rowspan="2" background="afbeeldingen/essentie7.gif">&nbsp;
            </td>
        <td width="270" height="493" rowspan="2" align="left" valign="top" background="afbeeldingen/essentie8.gif">     <span class="tekst"><br><br><br>
          <br>Wij vinden het niet belangrijk om ons eigen stempel ergens op te drukken. Het gaat erom dat de klant iets krijgt waar hij trots op is en wat natuurlijk aansluit bij de betreffende doelgroep.
          <br>In onze uitingen zorgen we er voor dat de boodschap zo helder mogelijk naar buiten wordt gebracht.<br>
      We houden niet van onnodige opschmuk. De essentie moet communiceren.<br><br></span></td>


        <td>
            <img src="afbeeldingen/spacer.gif" width="1" height="180" alt=""></td>



    </tr>



    <tr>
        <td width="235" height="514" rowspan="2" background="afbeeldingen/klein-2kolom_10.gif">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <img src="afbeeldingen/spacer.gif" width="1" height="313" alt=""></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td height="201" colspan="5" background="afbeeldingen/klein-2kolom_11.gif">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <img src="afbeeldingen/spacer.gif" width="1" height="201" alt=""></td>
            <span class="twitter">

    </tr>



</table>
</div></div>
<!-- End ImageReady Slices -->


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #wrapper set

```
position: relative
z-index: 100
```

For #twitter set

```
position: absolute
z-index: 110
```

You will also have to set Left and Top in the wrapper to set its position. In your HTML (or the rendered HTML)

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='twitter'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

replace your css with these

```
#twitter {
 height:auto;
 width:auto;
 z-index:100;
 margin-left:500px;
 margin-top:100px;
 border:solid 2px red;
}

#wrapper{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 border:solid 2px green;
}
```

the border color is just for your reference ... this will surely work...

Comment: it was not the direct solution, but i solved it by doing that first and then give some height and width to the wrapper. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position:absolute;` to the #twitter div.

Comment: Tried, but no success, i already have solved it! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a position property. z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Also IE has some bugs to do with z-index see: http://www.gobdg.com/blog/2009/04/positionrelative-z-index-ie-bug/

Hope this helps :D

Heres some CSS for you

```
<style type="text/css">
#twitter {
z-index:1;
position:absolute;
left:500px;
top:100px;
}

#wrapper{
margin: auto;
}

#content{
margin:auto;
height:800px;
}
</style>
```